# Is there a closed form formula for the recursive sequence: $x_n = x_{n-1} + \alpha\sqrt{x_{n-1}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form, recursion

I saw this link for closed form formula for a recursive sequence ([How to derive a closed form of a simple recursion?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/355963/how-to-derive-a-closed-form-of-a-simple-recursion))

However, what if my formula is:
$$x_n = x_{n-1} + \alpha\sqrt{x_{n-1}} \quad \text{ and } \quad x_0 = \beta \quad \text{ and }\quad\alpha,\beta> 0$$

Is there a closed form solution to determine the value of $x_n$ for a given $n$?

Bonus: If there is a closed form solution, is there an inverse? That is, if one is given a value $y$, can one deduce the *closest* $n$ such that $x_n$ is the closest to $y$ compared to any other possible $x_n$ value?

I couldn't figure out the mathemical formula for either question. Since we're CS engineers, we know that we could create a lookup table for the first 1 million values of $n$ and that should work for us. (It's arguably a reasonable solution, since we need to compute $x_n$ for 100 million values of $n$ (so obviously, $n$ will be the same thousands of times and so precomputing is not such a bad idea.) But still, it would "cleaner" if there were a closed form analytical solution to the above recursive sequence that we could use/consider.

Comment: Sad to say, it's very unlikely you'll find a closed form for general $\alpha$. There are extravagant ways of producing a closed form, but it'll probably be more computationally exhausting than just making a lookup table. This is equivalent to solving $\Delta y = \alpha \sqrt{y}$ and difference equations like this are pretty nasty.

Comment: @james.nixon I've solved it for $x_0=\beta=\frac{\alpha^2}9$.  See the end of my answer.

Comment: This looks like a heavily translated quadratic map, and if so, it is not solvable in general.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Well played, good sir! But I still stand by my comment, getting a function $x_n(\alpha,\beta)$ is surely impossible unless we start using infinite series and infinite integrals, and at that point it would be computationally far worse.

Comment: @james.nixon Indeed... the general case would be quite the challenge.  :D If I figure it out I'll let you know

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bonus question turns out to be easier to solve than the actual problem.  Note the problem can be rewritten as

$$x_{n+1}-x_n=\alpha\sqrt{x_n}$$

Consider a variation on this:

$$\frac{dy}{dt}=\underbrace{\lim_{h\to0}{y(t+h)-y(t)\over h}}_{\approx~y(t+1)-y(t)}=\alpha\sqrt{y(t)}$$

This is easily solved using calculus and gives

$$y(t)=\left(\frac{\alpha t}2+\sqrt{y(0)}\right)^2$$

Thus, the solution to your problem is approximately given by

$$x_n\approx\left(\frac{\alpha n}2+\sqrt\beta\right)^2$$

Note that:

$$y(t+1)-y(t)=\alpha\left(\frac{\alpha t}2+\sqrt{y(0)}\right)+\frac{\alpha^2}4$$

$$\alpha\sqrt{y(t)}=\frac{\alpha^2t}2+\alpha\sqrt{y(0)}$$

That is,

$$y(t+1)-y(t)=\alpha\sqrt{y(t)}+\frac{\alpha^2}4$$

So the approximation is pretty decently close.

Thus, the inverse $z_n$ is given by

$$z_n\approx\frac2\alpha\left(\sqrt n-\sqrt\beta\right)$$

Comment: I was just about to comment that it looks like $x_n = \Theta(n^2)$ whenever $x_0>0$. This is consistent with your approximation.  Your approximation is off by exactly $\beta$ if $x_0=0$.

Comment: @Michael I believe it might be possible to improve this using the Euler-Maclaurin formula, though that will get complicated very quickly.  :D And if $x_0\in[0,1)$... well, I honestly can't help it that the derivative isn't a perfect approximation of finite differences.

Comment: Just to be cute, it is possible to solve the difference equation $y(t+1) - y(t) = \alpha \sqrt{y}$. It's an incredibly nasty expression though. $y(t)$ is holomorphic, at least, in a neighborood of $\alpha_0$ where $\alpha \sqrt{\alpha_0} = \alpha_0 = \alpha^2 $. Because $\sqrt{\cdot}$ isn't entire though analytically continuing it is a bit arduous. You might be able to get it on $\mathbb{R}^+$, haven't checked thoroughly. And the formula takes you to hell and back and is almost useless.

Comment: Actually wait, arithmetic error! I can solve $y(t+1) - y(t) = \alpha \sqrt{y} - \alpha_0$. Got ahead of myself, back to the drawing board.

Comment: Lol, okay @james.nixon

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt, There I got it!

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt : Something is wrong with this exact answer, it does not hold. For $\alpha=1$ we have $$ ((n+1)/2 + 1/3)^2 \neq (n/2 + 1/3)^2 + (n/2 + 1/3)$$

Comment: @Michael Did you use $x_0\ne\frac{\alpha^2}9$?

Comment: Oh, it appears I am off... lemme check my algebra real quick...

Comment: @Michael Aha... sadly, it is impossible for $x_n=(mn+b)^2$.

Comment: Yes, but the upper bound $x_n \leq \frac{\alpha^2}{4}(n + b)^2$ holds for $b$ chosen to satisfy the initial condition on $x_0$ (see my edited answer).

Comment: @Michael Well of course.  It likewise follows from my differential equations, since $x\mapsto x+\alpha\sqrt x$ is strictly increasing.

Answer (score 3):

Some notes on the asymptotic behavior of the sequence in questions.

- You are iterating the function $f(x) = x + \alpha \sqrt{x}$. For positive $\alpha$, this will obviously produce a growing sequence, and it is not hard to see that it will grow to infinity.
- If you define $g(x) = \sqrt{x^2 + \alpha x}$, you can verify that $f(x^2) = g(x)^2$.
- Defining $y_n = \sqrt{x_n}$, you can see that $y_n = g(y_{n-1})$.

Consider the expansion (valid for large $x$)

$$g(x) = \sqrt{x^2 + \alpha x} = x \sqrt{1 + \frac{\alpha }{x}} = x \left( 1 + \frac{\alpha}{2x} - \frac{\alpha^2}{8x^2} + o(x^{-2})\right)$$
$$= x + \frac{\alpha}{2} - \frac{\alpha^2}{8x} + o(x^{-1})$$

We can thus infer that, for large $n$

$$y_n \approx \frac{\alpha n}{2}$$

Feeding this back into the asymptotic expansion, we can show further that:

$$y_n \approx \frac{\alpha}{4}(2n - \log n)$$

Deriving extra terms in this expansion is possible, but not necessarily enlightening.

One can then infer that, for large $n$,

$$x_n \approx \frac{\alpha^2}{16}\left(2n - \log n\right)^2$$

This does not really touch on the dependence on $\beta$, which is harder to broach by studying asymptotics.

Comment: Interesting approach.  I would have to look and think more closely at your answer to verify the details, but I give +1 since I have a back-of-the-envelope lower bound on $x_n$ for all $n$ of roughly the same structure as in your answer ($x_n \geq \frac{\alpha^2}{4}(n-b_n)^2$ with $\frac{\alpha^2}{4}b_0^2 = x_0$ and with $|b_n| \approx \log(n)$). I use a completely different method (remarkably the $log(n)$ that you get pops up in my argument since I sum a $1/k$ sequence). I think your $\log(n)$ perhaps inspired my calculation, even though I do not quite follow how you got your $\log$.  hehe.

Comment: The closed form is not too bad $x_n=\beta -\alpha\,  \zeta \left(-\frac{1}{2},n\right)+\alpha\,  \zeta \left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)$

Comment: @Michael i obtain the $\log n$ in the same way, just didnt include the details.

Comment: @Raffaele not sure what function you are referring to - is this some partial sum of the zeta function? your solution also has (asymptotically) linear dependence on $\alpha$, whereas mine has quadratic dependence - perhaps you could show your working?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a proof that $0\leq x_n \leq c (n+1)^2$ for $c = \max[\frac{\alpha^2}{4}, x_0]$, assuming $x_0>0$.

Proof (induction): Suppose $0\leq x_n \leq c(n+1)^2$ is true for some nonnegative integer $n$ (it clearly holds for $n=0$). We prove it also holds for $n+1$. Clearly $x_{n+1}\geq 0$. Then, we have
\begin{align}
x_{n+1} &= x_n + \alpha \sqrt{x_n} \\
&\leq c(n+1)^2 + \alpha c^{1/2}(n+1) \quad \mbox{[since it holds for $n$]}\\
&\leq (c^{1/2}(n+1) + \frac{\alpha}{2})^2  \\
&=(c^{1/2}n + c^{1/2} + \frac{\alpha}{2})^2 \\
&\overset{(a)}{\leq}(c^{1/2}n + 2c^{1/2})^2\\
&=c(n+2)^2
\end{align}
where (a) holds because $c^{1/2} + \frac{\alpha}{2} \leq 2c^{1/2}$ (since $c$ was chosen to ensure $c \geq \frac{\alpha^2}{4}$). $\Box$

---

EDIT: Here is a bound with a coefficient $\alpha^2/4$ regardless of $x_0$ (along the lines of the discussion in the comments below).

Claim:  $x_n \leq g(n+b)^2$ for all $n \in \{0, 1, 2, ...\}$, with $g=\alpha^2/4$ and $b = \frac{2\sqrt{x_0}}{\alpha}$.

Proof (induction): Suppose true for some $n \in \{0, 1, 2...\}$ (it indeed holds true for $n=0$). We prove for $n+1$.  We have: 
\begin{align}
x_{n+1} &= x_n + \alpha \sqrt{x_n} \\
&\leq g(n+b)^2 + \alpha g^{1/2}(n+b) \\
&= g(n+b)^2 + 2g(n+b) \quad \mbox{[since $\alpha = 2g^{1/2}$]}\\
&= g(n+1+b)^2 - g\\
&\leq g(n+1+b)^2
\end{align}
$\Box$

Comment: This upper-bound seems to get the correct coefficient of $n^2$, namely $c = \max[\frac{\alpha^2}{4}, \frac{\alpha^2}{9}]=\frac{\alpha^2}{4}$, in the simplybeautifulart case when $x_0 = \alpha^2/9$.

Comment: More precisely, the minimum $c$ is $\frac{\alpha^2}4$.  Asymptotically as $n\to\infty$, then $x_n=\frac{\alpha^2}4n^2+\mathcal O(1)$.

Comment: Er, I meant to say $\mathcal O(n)$ in my last comment.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt : I suppose the $c$ dependence on the initial condition in the above argument can be removed by considering the form $x_n=c(n+b)^2$ (rather than $c(n+1)^2$), and then we can just choose $b$ to ensure the initial condition, so we are free to choose $c=\alpha^2/4$ (rather than $c = \max[\frac{\alpha^2}{4}, x_0]$).

Comment: That's going to get you extremely close to the last half of my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Aha! So this is an answer to a comment that @SimplyBeautifulArt made. It is possible to solve

$$y(t+1) - y(t) = \alpha \sqrt{y}$$

For $t\in\mathbb{R}^+$, and we can have $y(0) = \beta$ for any $\beta \in \mathbb{R}^+$. I just thought it'd be nice to state such problems are solvable. Sadly it's computationally a **nightmare** but it is possible.

Pay close attention.

Start with the equation

$$g(\xi) = \xi + \alpha \sqrt{\xi}$$

The trouble I was having is that this funcion isn't holomorphic in a neighborhood of $0$, so I was getting divergent answers. But, if we invert it, we do get one.

Solving for $\xi$ in $g(\xi) = \xi + \alpha \sqrt{\xi}$, gives

$$\xi = \frac{\alpha^2}{2} - \frac{\alpha\sqrt{\alpha^2+4g(\xi)}}{2} + g(\xi)$$

Let $f(x) = \frac{\alpha^2}{2} - \frac{\alpha\sqrt{\alpha^2+4x}}{2} + x$, and $f(0) = 0$ and $f'(0) = 0$. Luckily $f$ is holomorphic in a neighborhood of $0$ now so long as $\alpha > 0$. It also follows that

$$f(g(x)) = x$$

Because of this our function can be conjugated to $x^n$, determining $n$ is equivalent to determining the order of the zero of $f$ at zero. Or that

$$f(x) = h^{-1}(h(x)^n)$$

for $|x| < \delta$ small and a nice unique $h$. Let
$$f^{\circ t}(x) = h^{-1}(h(x)^{n^t})$$

such that $f(f^{\circ t}(x)) = f^{\circ t+1}(x)$. And, more importantly,

$$g(f^{\circ t}(x)) = f^{\circ t-1}(x)$$. Let

$$y(t) = f^{\circ -t}(x)$$ which is defined on $\mathbb{R}$ by analytic continuation for $0 < x < \delta$, and

$$g(y(t)) = y(t+1)$$

Here comes the magic

$$g(y(t)) = y(t) + \alpha \sqrt{y(t)} = y(t+1)$$

and

$$y(t+1) - y(t) = \Delta y = \alpha \sqrt{y}$$

Finding $\tilde{y}$ such that $\tilde{y}(0) = \beta$ simply involves shifting the value $t$. Take care to notice that $y$ is analytic as well and tends to $0$ as $t \to -\infty$ and tends to $\infty$ as $t \to \infty$.

*That's what I was looking for!*

Comment: Hm, when you put it that way, its just an [Abel equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel_equation).

Comment: Egggggggsactly!

Comment: Why the 'egg'?  :P

Comment: The comment was too short otherwise

Comment: Lol$\color{white}{...}$

Comment: That's thinking outside the box!